# What is the IP address value in the listen field?

Tags: nginx

I'm looking at an example from here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

The listen value is the IP and port. Does this refer to the IP address of the client or the IP address of the target server? If its the later, then does this mean that 1 machine can have more than 1 IP?

```
server {
    listen      192.168.1.1:80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    ...
}

server {
    listen      192.168.1.1:80;
    server_name example.net www.example.net;
    ...
}

server {
    listen      192.168.1.2:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's server's IP address. Server could (and usually have) more than one IP address. At least it's external IP (e.g. 192.168.1.1) and local IP (127.0.0.1). But it is not unusual to have more IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets the interface to listen on.

If your machine has more than one interface (or several IP-addresses on single  interface), Nginx is able to listen only on selected interfaces.

Comment: If as I understand an interface is a unique ip/port pair, what do you mean by "several IP-adresses on a single interface" ? Did you mean several ip adresses on a single port ?